# Determine if the following is subspace of p3?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm Confused about if this a subspace or not?

A)all polynomials of the form a0+a1+a2x^2+a3x^3 where a1= a2

B)all polynomials of the form a0+a1x where a0 and a1 are real numbers

please help

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Let $A$ be the set of polynomials in question A.  You have to check four things.

1. Is $A$ a subset of a known vector space?  Yes, it is a subset of $\Bbb P_3$.
2. Does $A$ contain the zero polynomial?  The zero polynomial in $\Bbb P_3$ is
   $$c(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3x^2=0+0x+0x^2+0x^3\ .$$
   Does this satisfy the condition $c_1=c_2$?
3. Take two polynomials in $A$, say
   $$a(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3\quad\hbox{and}\quad b(x)=b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3\ .$$
   Since they are in $A$ we have $a_1=a_2$ and $b_1=b_2$.  Add these to get
   $$c(x)=a(x)+b(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3x^3\ .$$
   Now you need to find $c_0$ etc in terms of $a_0,b_0$ etc, and decide whether it is true that $c_1=c_2$.
4. Do something similar to (3) but involving scalar multiplication.